# Why arrow function has to be declared above the caller function

Tags: javascript, this, arrow-functions, javascript-function-declaration

In a javascript file, when I declare a function using `function` keyword, I can placed my function after my caller function, something like

```js
// test.js
function myCaller() {
   foo('hello world');    // this works!
   this.foo('hello world');  // this works!
}
function foo(text) {
   console.log('foo called!', text);
}
myCaller()
```

but if I turned the `foo` into an arrow function, and placed it at same position, then in `myCaller` function, it said `foo` is not defined, also it won't work if I use `this` keyword to locate the `foo` function, which I assume the `this` refers to global/document level

```js
// test.js
function myCaller() {
   foo('hello world');    // es-lint warning: 'foo' was used before it was defined
   this.foo('hello world');  // compilation error: foo is not defined
}
const foo = (text) => {
   console.log('foo called!', text);
}
myCaller();
```

- I was wrong, I thought the 2nd approach without using `this` does not work because of javascript compilation error of `not defined`, but it was actully my eslint error - `'foo' was used before it was defined`, does it mean it's not recommend to do this way?

Why is that and does it mean we have to declare the arrow function always above `caller` function? Is there any alternative way to solve that?

```js
const foo = (text) => {
   console.log('foo called!', text);
}
// test.js
function myCaller() {
   foo('hello world');    // this works! no es-lint warning now
   this.foo('hello world');  // no compilation error but there is a run-time error : 'this.foo is not a function'
}

myCaller();
```

In addition, I found when declare the arrow function inside a javascript class, it would work with `this` keyword only with caller function being arrow function as well, if caller function is with `function` keyword, this will not work...

```js
// myTest.js
class myTest {
   myCaller() {
      foo('hello world');    // compilation error: foo is undefined
   }
   myCaller2 = () => {
     this.foo('hello world'); //this works!
   }
   foo = (text) => {
      console.log('foo called!', text);
   }
}
new myTest().myCaller();
new myTest().myCaller2();
```

Comment: nothing to do with arrow, has to do with scope of `const`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54933689/arrow-function-hoisting-in-node

Comment: also, `this.foo` would subsequently fail even if const foo was above myCaller - since const and let variables are not added to the "global" object - `this` would likely be the global object (window on a browser) in your code

Comment: @JaromandaX should I remove the `const`? I cannot remove the `const`...if I remove the `const`, there is compile error said `foo is not defined`

Comment: @BaruchMashasha thanks for the link, but I don't think that helps here, as I am not executing `myCaller` function, as it's already generated compilation error, in addition, why it works when it uses `function` keyword but just not for arrow function?

Comment: @JaromandaX, yes I assume the `this` would be global object as well, then why when declaring the arrow function, it complains `foo is not defined`, but when declares using `function` keyword then using `this.foo`, it works?

Comment: `foo('hello world')` in your second example does *not* produce any error…!

Comment: Arrow functions are defined in scope. See this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: @deceze, sorry my bad, it was actually an eslint warning "foo was used before it was defined"

Comment: `function foo`, like `var foo` in the global scope will be part of the global scope ... `let` or `const` are not

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX, if `let` or `const` won't be considered at scope level, then why it works when working within `class` here? Or do you mean they wouldn't work with `global` scope specifically?

Comment: `let foo` in the global scope won't "create" a global.foo (i.e. `this.foo` in the global scope) whereas `var foo` or `function foo` does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any variables (except `let` and `const` variables) that you declare or functions that you define in global context (say, directly in test.js) will be attached to Window object. So, when you write,

```
// test.js
function myCaller() {
   foo('hello world');    // this works!
   this.foo('hello world');  // this works!
}
function foo(text) {
   console.log('foo called!', text);
}
myCaller()
```

Both `myCaller` and `foo` are attached to window object as properties. Now you can refer to them either directly like `foo()`(this is implicit here) or `this.foo()` or even `window.foo()`. Since js uses hoisting, these variables or functions are first attached to the context and then starts executing.

But `const` and `let` are not attached to the Window object (otherwise they would be accessible everywhere, behaving exactly like `var`). So when you write

```
// test.js
function myCaller() {
   foo('hello world');
   this.foo('hello world');
}
const foo = (text) => {
   console.log('foo called!', text);
}
myCaller();
```

Javascript engine scans through the entire script to see if there are any variables or functions defined. In this hoisting phase, if it finds a `const` or `let`, it allocates memory for them but won't make them part of Window object. So, when you are referring to `this` in global context, it is referring to window object and `foo` is not a property of window object. That is why, even if you put `const foo` above `myCaller` definition, it won't work.

In case of class, if you try to call `foo()` directly without referring to this, it tries to access it from the enclosing contexts, where it is not defined in your example. So it throws error. If you define another `foo()` outside the class with `var` or directly as `foo = (text) => ...`, it will work.

(The `this` may not be always referring to global context. Functions and classes can have their own custom context, and `this` would refer to that context. But when no custom context is defined by the functions or classes, the global context will be the one the `this` keyword would be referring to. The `this` is undefined for functions and classes by default in strict mode. There are several such caveats to be taken into consideration.)

Comment: You should explain why `this` inside `myCaller` is (or might not) be the global object…

Comment: `foo()` inside the class isn’t necessarily looked up from a *global* context, just from any surrounding scope.

Comment: JavaScript is also *compiled*, just on an as-needed basis. It can still throw compilation errors; syntax errors are thrown in the compilation/parsing phase. That’s distinct from a runtime error.

Comment: Thank you @chethan7! It explained very well! One thing I would like to understand betteris, in case of class, if I declare `foo()` outside my class, then I can call `foo()` directly inside my class method, does it mean that now it's because the `foo()` is attached to the `global windows` context and that's why I can call it inside my class method?

Comment: And you mentioned `That is why, even if you put const foo above myCaller definition,  it won't work.` Actually if I directly call the `foo()` without `this`, it did work...It's just not work when I call `this.foo()`, 
but since you mentioned, when met with `const` or `let`, JS allocates memory for them but not make them part of Window object, that'd prob explain why `this.foo()` not work because currently the `this` refers to windows context, hwever, why calling without `this` would work this time?